# How to get Custom Button to open in same Tab/Window in Lightning Community?

Tags: community, custom-button, visual-workflow, lightning-community, quickaction

I have a very simple Custom button in my Lightning Community that opens to a flow, but the custom button opens in a new tab/window even when I set it to open in the existing window.

This flow works, but I want it to use the existing window. Is there a way to make the custom button open in the existing tab/window instead?

Also just wanted to mention, the only reason I am going the Custom Button route and not an Lightning Action is because Salesforce automatically makes a Lightning Action on Case part of the publisher, which I don't want. If you know of a way to make the Case action act like a button instead and display at the top right of the record, that would be preferred.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to find solution on this?